# Highest entry from group by and compare to another value using having

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, max, having

This is what I want:

*Look if the highest created from the same FK is more than X days old.*

This is how the data is structured (this is not the result from the query below):

**table_1**

```
id     |      FK_table_2      |     created
-------------------------------------------------------
1      |      20              |     2013-11-12 12:13:14
2      |      20              |     2013-11-12 11:10:12
3      |      21              |     2013-10-02 12:53:20
4      |      21              |     2013-09-02 12:54:20
```

**Note:** Doing a subquery will be to slow.

What I come up with is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
GROUP BY FK_table_2
HAVING MAX(created) < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

I'm worried that *HAVING MAX(created)* has not garantuee to use the highest created.

Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: You are worried? Didn't you try it?

Comment: The result seems to be good, but its to much data to be 100% sure.

Comment: If you have to add your `id` to the output, which based on `select *` you should, then that query is not correct. What is your expected output in a tabular format?

Comment: The table_1 above is not the output, it's the database data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use a MAX clause, you can surely just select all rows older than 3 days and do your work on them.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FK_table_2 FROM table_1
WHERE created > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

*Update* this won't work :-(

Comment: The problem is that groups that contain old create will match. Say its 1 minute instead of 3 days. Then FK 21 will match if time is 12:54:21

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT FK_table_2,max(created)
FROM table_1
where created < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
GROUP BY FK_table_2
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the GROUP BY is applied before the WHERE, so the created can be any created in the same FK group.

Comment: this is the order in which query executes

Comment: 1. FROM clause 2. WHERE clause 3. GROUP BY clause 4. HAVING clause 5. SELECT clause 6. ORDER BY clause

Comment: Yes, that could be correct. but the WHERE will match elder entries, which will make the result wrong.

Comment: where clause will filter date by interval of 3 than max will be executed on that data.